# Async calls to a synchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, ecmascript-6

So in javascript Im trying to understand the use for callbacks and when its appropriate to use them. Can an asynchronous function, call a synchronous function in javascript?

Comment: Did you have a special case in your mind?

Comment: In general: sure. You might want to clarify why you're in doubt about that.

Comment: Async/Sync functions don't differ in how they are called but how they deliver their result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, take a look at the following code snippet

```js
// a synchronous function which returns sum
function syncFunction(x){
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 1; i<=x; i++){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

function asyncFunction(x, callback){
    // setTimeout makes this a asynchronous function which calls x=0,3,6,9 before x=1,4,7 and before x=2,5,8
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(syncFunction(x));
    }, (x%3)*1000);
}

for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    asyncFunction(i, function(sum){
        console.log(sum);
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks I was looking for a simple implementation to demonstrate how it could be done!